# centering text inside circular shape using bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I am using Bulma and CSS to style my angular app, am trying to create circles with numbers centered inside them and text beside each circle here is an example of the desired output :

[image]

Here is the output I am getting right now :

[image]

How do I fix it and center the text inside the circles without losing the aspect ratio?
and maybe also hide it from showing on smaller screens

This is the code I used :

```
.circle {
  background: #f8faff;
  border: 1px dashed #7494ec;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
}
```

```
  <div class="columns is-centered is-vcentered">
        <div class="columns column is-4">
          <div class="column circle has-text-centered">1</div>
          <span class="column">Select source</span>
        </div>
        <div class="columns column is-4">
          <div class="column circle has-text-centered">2</div>
          <span class="column">Upload Files</span>
        </div>
        <div class="columns column is-4">
          <div class="column circle has-text-centered">3</div>
          <span class="column"> Extract Data</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that using Bulma grid system is the right way to get the expected result. I would use flexbox to achieve this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.circle {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.text {
  flex-grow: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="text">My text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="text">My text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="text">My text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the text centered inside the circles:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.circle {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.text {
  flex-grow: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"><div class="text">My text</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"><div class="text">My text</div></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"><div class="text">My text</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2nd edit:

If you want the text centered inside the circles:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 0;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.circle {
  flex-grow: 0;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: red;
  margin-right: 10px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.text {
  flex-grow: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"><div class="text">1</div></div>
    <div class="text">My text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"><div class="text">2</div></div>
    <div class="text">My text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="circle"><div class="text">3</div></div>
    <div class="text">My text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do i center the text inside the circles thought, I tried both `has-text-centered` and `  align-content: center` they don't seem to do the trick

Comment: You can set your circles as flexbox too, just like I did with `.item`, and define `justify-content: center;` and `align-items: center;`. Then put your text in it and remove the `.text` div.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can see how to do this.

Comment: Am having trouble keeping the text inside and beside the circles, kind like combining both your answer ( exactly like the desired output I showed in the question )

Comment: I added an example which looks exactly like your image.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that is very much appreciated